# How to solve pandas issues with iterrows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, iterator

I was volunteered to help a rural library with some tasks they have. They want to send messages to their members. With the information they gave me, they would like to have the output I show later.
They have the following `.csv` file (this is an example):

```
import pandas as pd
file= ("biblioteca.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', dtype='str')
df
```

This is the content:

```
    Fecha   Socio   Doc Nombre  Libro   Volumenes   Dias_Vto
0   9/1/2021    1   47890056    Ruben Dario Harry Potter - Espanol  1   28
1   4/2/2021    1   47890056    Ruben Dario Harry Potter - Ingles   1   16
2   3/3/2021    1   47890056    Ruben Dario El pajaro canta hasta morir 1   16
3   1/1/2021    1   47890056    Ruben Dario Criptonomicom   3   35
4   1/2/2021    2   46859754    Ernesto Sabato  Cuentos de la selva 1   6
5   5/3/2021    2   46859754    Ernesto Sabato  Los pajaros 1   12
6   2/2/2021    3   39845712    Jose Sacristan  Vida de un Ausente  1   21
7   2/2/2021    3   39845712    Jose Sacristan  Alter Ego   1   19
8   2/2/2021    3   39845712    Jose Sacristan  Cookbook    5   2
```

I created some functions that have the information they want to send to the members:

```
gb = df.groupby(['Socio'])

def nombre(fila):
    return ("Fecha {} Documento {}".format(fila.Fecha, fila.Doc))

def sucursal(fila):
    return ("Sucursal - Monte Castro")

def libros(fila):
    return ("Don {}, retiró el dia {}, el libro: {} que consta de {} volumen/es;1;   {}".format(fila.Nombre, fila.Fecha, fila.Libro, fila.Volumenes, fila.Doc))

def vencimiento(fila):
    return ("El libro {} vence dentro de {} dia/s.  {}".format(fila.Libro, fila.Dias_Vto, fila.Doc))

print('Resumen Biblioteca')

for k, gp in gb:

  for idx, fila in gp.iterrows():
    print('Fecha  - Nombre')
    print(nombre(fila))
    print('Sucursal biblioteca')
    print(sucursal(fila))  
    
   

    print('Libros solicitados')
    for idx, fila in gp.iterrows():
        print(libros(fila))
  
    print('Vencimientos')  
    for idx, fila in gp.iterrows():
        print(vencimiento(fila))
    
    print('FIN Socio - Biblioteca Sucursal - Monte Castro')
print('---------')
print()
print()
```

The problem with the iteration is that it is multiplying the headers as many times as iterates the rows for every single row. This is the the case for the first member (`Socio`).

```
Resumen Biblioteca  
Fecha  - Nombre  
Fecha 9/1/2021 Documento 47890056  
Sucursal biblioteca  
Sucursal - Monte Castro  
Libros solicitados  
Don Ruben Dario, retiró el dia 9/1/2021, el libro: Harry Potter - Espanol que consta de 1 volumen/es;1;   47890056  
Don Ruben Dario, retiró el dia 4/2/2021, el libro: Harry Potter - Ingles que consta de 1 volumen/es;1;   47890056  
Don Ruben Dario, retiró el dia 3/3/2021, el libro: El pajaro canta hasta morir que consta de 1 volumen/es;1;   47890056  
Don Ruben Dario, retiró el dia 1/1/2021, el libro: Criptonomicom que consta de 3 volumen/es;1;   47890056  
Vencimientos  
El libro Harry Potter - Espanol vence dentro de 28 dia/s.  47890056  
El libro Harry Potter - Ingles vence dentro de 16 dia/s.  47890056  
El libro El pajaro canta hasta morir vence dentro de 16 dia/s.  47890056  
El libro Criptonomicom vence dentro de 35 dia/s.  47890056  
FIN Socio - Biblioteca Sucursal - Monte Castro  
Fecha  - Nombre  
Fecha 4/2/2021 Documento 47890056  
Sucursal biblioteca  
Sucursal - Monte Castro  
Libros solicitados  
Don Ruben Dario, retiró el dia 9/1/2021, el libro: Harry Potter - Espanol que consta de 1 volumen/es;1;   47890056  
Don Ruben Dario, retiró el dia 4/2/2021, el libro: Harry Potter - Ingles que consta de 1 volumen/es;1;   47890056  
Don Ruben Dario, retiró el dia 3/3/2021, el libro: El pajaro canta hasta morir que consta de 1 volumen/es;1;   47890056  
Don Ruben Dario, retiró el dia 1/1/2021, el libro: Criptonomicom que consta de 3 volumen/es;1;   47890056      
Vencimientos    
El libro Harry Potter - Espanol vence dentro de 28 dia/s.  47890056  
El libro Harry Potter - Ingles vence dentro de 16 dia/s.  47890056  
El libro El pajaro canta hasta morir vence dentro de 16 dia/s.  47890056
El libro Criptonomicom vence dentro de 35 dia/s.  47890056
FIN Socio - Biblioteca Sucursal - Monte Castro
```

The expected output is:

```
Resumen Biblioteca  
Fecha  - Nombre  
Fecha 9/1/2021 Documento 47890056  
Sucursal biblioteca  
Sucursal - Monte Castro  
Libros solicitados  
Don Ruben Dario, retiró el dia 9/1/2021, el libro: Harry Potter - Espanol que consta de 1 volumen/es;1;   47890056  
Don Ruben Dario, retiró el dia 4/2/2021, el libro: Harry Potter - Ingles que consta de 1 volumen/es;1;   47890056  
Don Ruben Dario, retiró el dia 3/3/2021, el libro: El pajaro canta hasta morir que consta de 1 volumen/es;1;   47890056  
Don Ruben Dario, retiró el dia 1/1/2021, el libro: Criptonomicom que consta de 3 volumen/es;1;   47890056  
Vencimientos  
El libro Harry Potter - Espanol vence dentro de 28 dia/s.  47890056  
El libro Harry Potter - Ingles vence dentro de 16 dia/s.  47890056  
El libro El pajaro canta hasta morir vence dentro de 16 dia/s.  47890056  
El libro Criptonomicom vence dentro de 35 dia/s.  47890056  
FIN Socio - Biblioteca Sucursal - Monte Castro
```

For each of the members (`Socio`).

The same happens to all of the members.
I appreciate the help!!!

Comment: You have two for-loops inside the second one, which is also inside another loop. Do you need that many?

Comment: The First loop is for the groups, The first inside is for the header, the inside two are the info the library requires to show to the members.
The problem the loop for the heather, this should appear just once. The 2 inside works fine

Comment: You don't need to have 2 separate loops for "Libros solicitados" and "Vencimientos". You could just put those prints inside the first `for idx, fila in gp.iterrows():` and it will work fine.

Comment: I tried removing the 2nd loop but the result is far from expected. It is repeating the header and rows 1 by 1.... It is a nightmare

Comment: Could you post your expected output? It doesn't have to be every line, just the general idea with a few examples. That way, people can see exactly what you want.

Comment: Sure, I am editing the question with the output expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you need. The thing to keep in mind is not to iterate over `gb` a second time inside the first loop. Rather, iterate a second time over `fila`.

```
# Necessary change in order to account for the new for structure
def nombre(fila):
    return "Fecha {} Documento {}".format(fila.Fecha.iloc[0], fila.Doc.iloc[0])

for _, fila in gb:
    print('Fecha  - Nombre')
    print(nombre(fila))
    print('Sucursal biblioteca')
    print(sucursal())  

    print('Libros solicitados')
    for _, fila2 in fila.iterrows():
        print(libros(fila2))
        
    print('Vencimientos')  
    for _, fila2 in fila.iterrows():
        print(vencimiento(fila2))
```

Comment: Thanks, It is working better in terms of no repeating the header, but now the header has this output: ```Fecha  - Nombre  
Fecha 4    1/2/2021  
5    5/3/2021  
Name: Fecha, dtype: object Socio: 4    Ernesto Sabato  
5    Ernesto Sabato  
Name: Nombre, dtype: object  ```

Comment: You're right. I edited my answer to account for that.

Comment: Camilo, THANKS for the answer, I am learning python and this put me to think a lot. I appreciate your help!!! I will continue working on this volunteer project with new lessons learned. What is your recommendation to learn more about this online ?

Comment: Honestly, any simple googling will get you to a good start. However, I highly recommend Keith Galli's yt channel. He has many videos on this topic, as well as an introductory video on `pandas` with over a million views and it will likely give you a bigger picture on this library and its tools.

Comment: I will watch it on YT. I do no have the reputation yet to mark the answer as useful, but I really appreciate your time and help.